# how to check and replace an element in an array c++

Tags: c++

I'm taking in a string of input and putting it into an array, called complement, so that I can compare each element to "A", "G", "C", and "T" and make replacements to generate the complement of the DNA strand. I am trying to use this, but it doesn't work:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
  if(complement[i] == "T")
 complement[i] = "A";
```

I can't use the replace function because that goes through the entire array and does replacements altogether, but i need to go character by character so that AAGCT doesn't change A to T and then T back to A. I am doing this in C++, but any other language that could ease the situation would be ok. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of your array?

Comment: string comparison with == looks suspicious.

Comment: @dornhege, not if `complement` is an array of `std::string`.

Comment: `"T"` is a string with two characters in it, rather it should be `'T'`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are comparing a Character with a String. 'A' != "A" one is a char and the other one is a pointer.
So what you have to do is

```
if (complement[i] == 'T')
```

Comment: Thanks! simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `complement` is declared something like

```
char complement[]
```

Which is to say an array of `char`s. If that is indeed the case, then

```
if(complement[i] == "T")...
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

More importantly,

```
complement[i] = "A";
```

here you are assigning a C-string literal to a `char`, which probably won't end well.

I suggest brushing up on your C, more specifically, arrays, `char`s, C-strings and pointers.